# How to generate a "fake" slug in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-urls, slug

I saw in a video I didn't save that you could do something like this:

> [www.mysite.com/post/12345/this-is-a-title](http://www.mysite.com/post/12345/this-is-a-title)

Where the `12345` is the id and what actually is used to do the query and the `this-is-a-tilte` part is automatically assigned when loading the page and you can actually write whatever you want there and will still load the page.

How do I set this up in my path and do I still need a SlugField?

Answer (score 0):

you'll need `SlugField` field and the `slugify` function to auto-generate the slug from the title.

try the code below

`models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class Post(models.Model):
    """A model holding common fields to Post model."""

    slug = models.SlugField(_('slug'), max_length=255,
        unique=True, null=True, blank=True,
        help_text=_(
            'If blank, the slug will be generated automatically '
            'from the given title.'
        )
    )
    title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_('The title of the post.')
    )

[..]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    # Where the magic happens ..
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

`urls.py`:

```
    path('post/<id:pk>/<slug:slug>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a model with a title:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    # …
```

You can make a path that looks like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # …
    path('post/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

the view can then fetch the corresponding `Post` object and slugify the title. If the slug does not match, it redirects it to the correct slug:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.utils.text import slugify

def post_detail(request, pk, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    post_slug = sluglify(post.title)
    if slug != post_slug:
        # in case the slug does not match, redirect with the correct slug
        return redirect('post_detail', pk=pk, slug=post_slug)
    # … logic to render the object …
```